# Understanding a function definition in a header file

Tags: c

I am porting a software written to a specific microcontroller to another microcontroller but I have a problem in C language.

I would like to draw attention to the below mentioned functions defined inside [hal_spi_rf_trxeb.c](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwMfDD5kcvwscXE2UmF1YXlSdmM/view?usp=sharing) file.  Although I searched within the file I was not able to find the full function description for the following functions.

1. `TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_DONE()`
2. `TRXEM_SPI_RX()`
3. `TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_DONE()`
4. `TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_TX_DONE()`
5. `TRXEM_SPI_RX()`
6. `TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_MISO_LOW(x)`

After a bit more searching I figured that these functions exist in the header file itself.  More specifically [`inhal_spi_rf_trxeb.h`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwMfDD5kcvwsQzR2eEZZYTBfTDA/view?usp=sharing) file.

```
    /******************************************************************************
 * @fn          trx16BitRegAccess
 *
 * @brief       This function performs a read or write in the extended adress
 *              space of CC112X.
 *
 * input parameters
 *
 * @param       accessType - Specifies if this is a read or write and if it's
 *                           a single or burst access. Bitmask made up of
 *                           RADIO_BURST_ACCESS/RADIO_SINGLE_ACCESS/
 *                           RADIO_WRITE_ACCESS/RADIO_READ_ACCESS.
 * @param       extAddr - Extended register space address = 0x2F.
 * @param       regAddr - Register address in the extended address space.
 * @param       *pData  - Pointer to data array for communication
 * @param       len     - Length of bytes to be read/written from/to radio
 *
 * output parameters
 *
 * @return      rfStatus_t
 */
rfStatus_t trx16BitRegAccess(uint8 accessType, uint8 extAddr, uint8 regAddr, uint8 *pData, uint8 len)
{
  uint8 readValue;

  <span style="background-color:#ff0000;">TRXEM_SPI_BEGIN();</span>
  while(TRXEM_PORT_IN & TRXEM_SPI_MISO_PIN);
  /* send extended address byte with access type bits set */
 <span style="background-color:#ff0000;"> TRXEM_SPI_TX</span>(accessType|extAddr);
  TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_DONE();
  /* Storing chip status */
  readValue = TRXEM_SPI_RX();
  TRXEM_SPI_TX(regAddr);
  TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_DONE();
  /* Communicate len number of bytes */
  trxReadWriteBurstSingle(accessType|extAddr,pData,len);
```

`hal_spi_rf_trxeb.h` claims to have the function I was searching in the form of a macro. Those macros are shown below.

```
/******************************************************************************
 * MACROS
 */

/* Macros for Tranceivers(TRX) */
#define TRXEM_SPI_BEGIN()              st( TRXEM_PORT_OUT &= ~TRXEM_SPI_SC_N_PIN; NOP(); )
#define TRXEM_SPI_TX(x)                st( UCB0IFG &= ~UCRXIFG; UCB0TXBUF= (x); )
#define TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_DONE()          st( while(!(UCB0IFG & UCRXIFG)); )
#define TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_TX_DONE()       st( while(!(UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG)); )
#define TRXEM_SPI_RX()                 UCB0RXBUF
#define TRXEM_SPI_WAIT_MISO_LOW(x)     st( uint8 count = 200; \
                                           while(TRXEM_PORT_IN & TRXEM_SPI_MISO_PIN) \
                                           { \
                                              __delay_cycles(5000); \
                                              count--; \
                                              if (count == 0) break; \
                                           } \
                                           if(count>0) (x) = 1; \
                                           else (x) = 0; )
```

#### Questions

- I do not understand how these macros work.
- Could someone please tell me how a function has been defined in the header file?
- How can a function be defined in the header file itself?
- What does the function `st()` do?

Should you require, the whole project can be downloaded by [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwMfDD5kcvwsWmxGZ1BuUHpteTg/view?usp=sharing).

For more information you may view the linked header and source (`.h` and `.c`) files.

Comment: Why is there HTML in the middle of your C code?

Comment: This post has too many questions, and it's unclear what the problem is. Ask only one question at the time, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already said, those are not functions but rather macros. You can read about macros in the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html).

> A macro is a fragment of code which has been given a name. Whenever
>   the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro.

That's the summary. There's a lot more detail to it than that. But for starters you can think of macros as code replacement rules. Macros are expanded by the preprocessor before the compiler does it's job.

A simple example:

```
#define MY_PRINT_MACRO(string1, string2) printf("%s %s\n", string1, string2)

MY_PRINT_MACRO("hello", "world");
```

The preprocessor will change the second line to be:

```
printf("%s %s\n", "hello", "world");
```

And that is exactly what the compiler will see (it does not see `MY_PRINT_MACRO` at all).

Answer (score 0):

These are not functions but macros. Macros are basically being replaced by the code they represent before compilation (preprocessing).

Macros can be defined and redefined over header files.

st() function is not written in the context so not sure what it does.

Comment: #define st(x) do { x } while (__ LINE __ == -1)

Comment: this is also a macro which does a command once. 
it does x and then check the line number is -1 so it does not do it again.